# Android: Menu group in group doesn't work with android:visible?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a Menu, with checkable item and normal item in a `group`, which can be toggled (show/hide) under different conditions.

but i found that checkable item can only be defined in a `group`, so i made a menu xml as follow:

Resource Code

```
    <group android:id="@+id/adminMenu"
        android:visible="false">
        <group android:checkableBehavior="all">
            <item android:id="@+id/toggleConsole"
                android:title="Console Mode"/>
        </group>
        <item android:id="@+id/restartApp"
            android:title="Restart Game"/>
    </group>
```

What i expected:

[image]

But the problem is: The outer `group` still shows even if defined the property visible = false.

is it a bug or it's not even allowed (or not a best practice) by using encapsulated `group`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group cannot reside inside a group. You should just use a checkable item (don't know why you didn't):

```
<group android:id="@+id/adminMenu"
       android:visible="true">
    <item android:id="@+id/toggleConsole"
          android:checkable="true"
          android:title="Console Mode"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/restartApp"
          android:title="Restart Game"/>
</group>
```